# Finding a scalar potential given its set of stationary points

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals, lagrange-multiplier, multiple-integral

Given a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$
$$x^\star(t), y^\star(t), z^\star(t)\text{,}\quad 0\le t\le 1$$
I am looking for a scalar potential $V(x, y): \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, whose partial derivatives satisfy the following conditions,
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}(x^\star(t),y^\star(t)) &= 0\\
\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial y}(x^\star(t),y^\star(t))&=z^\star(t)\text{,}\\
\forall 0\le t\le 1\text{.}
\end{align*}
Any idea on how to find $V$?

**Less confusing formulation**

Given a curve $x^\star, y(x^\star)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I am looking for a scalar potential $V(x, y)$ having a specific gradient along that curve, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}(x^\star,y(x^\star)) &= 0\\
\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial y}(x^\star,y(x^\star))&=z(x^\star)\text{,}\\
\end{align*}
where $z: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a given function.

**Context**

This problem arises when one tries to derive the potential elastic energy of an elastic structure with two degrees of freedom $x$ and $y$ given its equilibrium path. The equilibrium path is the set of all the static equilibrium states the structure can be in when a force acts on it. This path can be represented by a curve in a three-dimension space: two dimensions for the degrees of freedom ($x$ and $y$), and a third dimension for the force $z$ acting on one of the degree of freedom ($y$ in this case). Each triplet of points $(x^\star(t), y^\star(t), z^\star(t))$ corresponds to a static configuration of the structure.

When on tries to find the equilibrium path of an elastic structure whose elastic energy is given by $V(x, y)$, the classic approach consists of forming the *total potential energy* $\Pi$ defined as
$$\Pi = V(x, y) - zy\text{,}$$
where $z$ represents the external force acting on the degree of freedom $y$. We consider the case where no external force acts on the degree of freedom $x$.

The static equilibrium states ($x^\star$, $y^\star$, $z^\star$) are the stationary points of the potential $\Pi$ (w.r.t the variables $x$ and $y$), which leads to the following set of equations
\begin{equation*}
0=\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}(x^\star, y^\star),\quad
0=\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial y}(x^\star, y^\star) - z^\star\text{.}
\end{equation*}

Comment: An equivalent way of stating the problem: find the scalar potential $\Pi=V(x,y)-zy$ given its stationary points with respect to x and y. Hence the title.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject the two conditions inside the Taylor series of $V$ and... the job is basically done ! Concretely, let's recall that a bivariate Taylor expansion around a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by
$$
V(x,y) = \sum_{n,m\ge0} \left.\frac{\partial^{n+m}V}{\partial x^n \partial y^m}\right|_{x=x_0,y=y_0} \frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!} \frac{(y-y_0)^m}{m!}.
$$
Choosing $x_0 = x^\star$ and $y_0 = y^\star$, we end up with
$$
V(x,y) = a_{00} + z^\star(y-y^\star) + \sum_{n,m\ge2} a_{nm} \frac{(x-x^\star)^n}{n!} \frac{(y-y^\star)^m}{m!},
$$
where $a_{nm} = \partial_x^n \partial_y^m V(x^\star,y^\star)$ are free parameters.

Comment: I think here $V$ is depends on $t$. But originally, the $V$ is a general potential function independent of $t$.

Comment: @Abezhiko Thanks! Definitely an interesting approach! As far as I understand, the only issue I see with the potential $V$ that you constructed is that it satisfies both conditions as soon as $y=y^\star$ even when $x \neq x^\star$, right? I should have been more precise by mentioning that $(x^\star, y^\star)$ are the *only* points that satisfy the 'stationary' conditions.

Comment: @Offlaw The potential can depend on $t$ implicitely via $x^\star(t)$ and $y^\star(t)$, that is not an issue. The expressions $x^\star(t)$ and $y^\star(t)$ are allowed to appear in the expression of $V$.

Comment: @duc4rm3 Sorry! I misunderstood the question. I though you want a potential function on $\mathbb{R}^2$  having the specific gradient along a given curve.

Comment: @Offlaw You're exactly right. Given a curve $x^\star(t),y^\star(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I am looking for a scalar potential $V(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ having a specific gradient that changes along that curve.

Comment: @duc4rm3 Then $V$ can't have $t$ in the expression, as far as I understand, because it will make the potential *time* dependent.

Comment: @Abezhiko Sorry, I accepted this answer too quickly. I think that indeed Offlaw is right: $V$ should not depend on $t$. Otherwise, I cannot plot the surface $V(x,y)$ for example.

Comment: @duc4rm3 $V$ shouldn't depend *explicitly* on $t$, but only through the variables $(x,y,z)$ and $(x^\star,y^\star,z^\star)$. Your two formulations are actually equivalent under the change of variable $x = x(t)$